# Sidebar Widget Text in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, sidebar

I created the site uptimber.com, when viewed in google chrome it looks fine, however in other browsers the sidebar menu get very messed up. Is there a plugin or any quick fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line on `#sidebar-one` id in your CSS: `position: absolute;`

```
#sidebar-one {
    position: absolute; /* Remove this line */
    top: 110px;
    right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me a lot of time figuring it out myself! Do you have a small explaination why position:absolute affected it that way?